# How to check a server availibiliy from multiple countries in Zabbix

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix, icmp

I want to use zabbix to monitor the ICMP and HTTP protocols on a server. Zabbix server is in France and the host is in USA. I want to monitor its accessibility from USA, France and Germany for example, just like uptimerobot.com or hetrixtools.com. Is there any way to implement such a system with zabbix?
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need servers in those locations. If you have that, put either [Zabbix proxy](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/distributed_monitoring/proxies) or [Zabbix agent](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/concepts/agent) on each of those servers, then monitor your target host from each server.

If you are using Zabbix proxies, each target from each location would be a separate host - for example, you would have hosts named `target-from_France`, `target-from_Germany` etc. If you would place these hosts in the same group, you could use [Zabbix aggregate items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/aggregate) to calculate statistics across all locations (for example, the average transfer speed).

Comment: Thank you. If I use Zabbix proxy can I have an aggregation of the results to decide whether a host is really down or not? I mean is it possible to have the result of icmpping from USA, Gernamy and France for a host, and if all of them showed the server down then I notify the customer that your server is down?

Comment: Yes, you can use the new zabbix 3.2 event correlation for this. Only inform the customer when all pings are unavailable. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/event_correlation

Comment: Event correlation seems to be an overkill for this - the aggregate items, available for a long time, should do the job. I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Thank you guys. I go for it.